# How to keep the flutter plugin code private So that user can not see Plugin code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

As we have developing a flutter plugin and we don't want to share any source code of Flutter, Android and iOS. If Customers take our plugin for their app there is possibilities to see source code. So I want to know if there is any way to implement.

Comment: you can put the plugin on GitHub as private repo and use it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to actually "not to show a source code" because dart pub fetches your plugin and holds its copy in pub cache - so it is always available to see its code. On other hand - if you have some features (cloud computation, video streaming, geo computations ) that could be shared as an API - you may share that feature via access tokens. Examples: Pusher, Google maps, You tube.